# Do a web request in yew.rs v0.19

Tags: rust, webassembly, yew

In yew 0.2 `Request::get` worked fine but now `yew::services` doesn't exist, how can I make a request to `/api/ping`? do I need javascript?

Comment: https://yew.rs/docs/migration-guides/yew/from-0_18_0-to-0_19_0#services

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using [reqwasm](https://crates.io/crates/reqwasm).

For reqwasm 0.4.0:

```
use reqwasm::http::Request;

Request::get(url)
    .send()
    .await
    .unwrap();
```

And/or you could use `web_sys::{Request, RequestInit}` and `wasm_bindgen_futures::JsFuture`.

For web-sys 0.3.55 and wasm-bindgen-futures 0.4.28:

```
let mut opts = RequestInit::new();
opts.method("GET");
let request = Request::new_with_str_and_init(url, &opts)?;
let window = web_sys::window().unwrap();
JsFuture::from(window.fetch_with_request(&request)).await?;
```

Comment: Reqwasm didn't worked fine for me, but web_sys + reqwest did. Thank you!

Comment: May I ask why it didn't work? Maybe is material for another question, but it'd be nice to know it.

Answer (score 0):

Yew uses `web-sys` to access browser specific APIs. The `fetch` API can be called from rust by following the guide from Yew and `web-sys`.

[Yew web-sys Integration Docs](https://yew.rs/docs/concepts/basic-web-technologies/web-sys)

[`web-sys` fetch Docs](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/examples/fetch.html)

Comment: 0.19 doesn't support this method anymore, apparently.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `gloo-net` as suggested by the official yew [tutorial]([https://yew.rs/docs/tutorial#:~:text=Fetching%20data%20(using,the%20following%20crates%3A)](https://yew.rs/docs/tutorial#:%7E:text=Fetching%20data%20(using,the%20following%20crates%3A))

```rs
use gloo_net::http::Request;

Request::get(URL)
   .send()
   .await
   .unwrap();
```